# Prevent build attempt when deploying single jar on Google App Engine with java11

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, java-11

I have a spring java project which is built on a CI system outside of google cloud. The final build command is `gradle bootJar` . I want to deploy the resulting jar to Google App Engine.

The suggested way to do so is just calling `gcloud app deploy my.jar` . Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work for me as the application needs more RAM than provided by the default instance type (F1 = 256MB). So I have to specify the instance type somehow.

My current approach is to create a custom `app.yaml` - and also a `.gcloudignore` to ensure that only the jar is uploaded. My `app.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
runtime: java11
instance_class: F2
entrypoint: java -noverify -jar my.jar
```

While the instance is working, the instance logs indicate that a build is tried in parallel (log excerpt):

```
Starting Step #5 - "builder"
Step #5 - "builder": Already have image (with digest): eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200913_11_0_RC00
Step #5 - "builder": === Java - App Engine (google.java.appengine@0.9.0) ===
Step #5 - "builder": DEBUG: Using GOOGLE_RUNTIME: java11
Step #5 - "builder": DEBUG: Using config appengine.Config{Runtime:"java11", Entrypoint:appengine.Entrypoint{Type:"User", Command:"java -noverify -jar my.jar", WorkDir:""}, MainExecutable:""}
Step #5 - "builder": === Utils - Label Image (google.utils.label@0.0.1) ===
Finished Step #5 - "builder"
```

These build attempts do not happen when I specify the jar directly in `gcloud app deploy`, but as said this fails due to memory.

Ideally, I want to use my own app.yaml in order to specify other configuration options as well. But I don't want to have a build happening all the time.

So is there a way to either suppress these build attempts or, alternatively, pass additional configuration options which would usually be in an `app.yaml` to a `gcloud app deploy my.jar` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible, if you use a `app.yaml` to deploy your app a build will always be triggered and if you use `gradle` you will not be able to select the `instance_class` like the `app.yaml` allows you to do. So there is no optimal solution for your problem, However there is an alternative for this, which is to use App Engine Flex to deploy a container with your `my.jar` file.

You can check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/run-simple-jar-application-in-docker-container-1) for how to create a docker file to run a `.jar` app. Also in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-flex#deploying_to_a_custom_runtime) you can see how you can deploy that docker containing your jar file to App Engine Flex, this configuration will also create an `app.yaml` file and in that `app.yaml` you can specify the infrastructure that you will need to run your app. As you can see in this second [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml), you could add the following block of configurations to the `app.yaml` to let App Engine Flex know how much infrastructure you need for your app's container:

```
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5
```

**NOTE**: Since you already have your app up and running in an instance of App Engine Standard I would say that the proposed alternative is not worth the effort if you can simply ignore the build logs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Still hoping that there might be another option and waiting for it a little longer. Will make this the answer then in a 1-2 days.

Comment: @DirkBolte Could you please accept the answer if it solved the issue you are were facing?